# Problem performing segue from tableview to viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to perform a segue from a `UITableView` with news. If you push one of the news, it performs a segue to the specific news you selected.

It is easy and I have done it a few times... but I don't know what am I doing wrong this time.

The **NewsDetailViewController** is like this:

```
class NewsDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var newsImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var newsTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newsDate: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newsText: UILabel!

var newsLink: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Hides the navigation bar.
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

}


@IBAction func closeNews(_ sender: UIButton) {
       navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}

}
```

And the segue in the **NewsTableViewController** is like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("you selected the row: \(indexPath.row)")
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNewsDetail", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToNewsDetail" {

        if let destination = segue.destination as? NewsDetailViewController {

            destination.newsLink = "whateverlink"
            destination.newsTitle.text = "whatevertitle"

        }

    }

}
```

And the line: `destination.newsLink = "whateverlink"`
Works perfectly.

But the line: `destination.newsTitle.text = "whatevertitle"`
Throws a

> fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
>   Optional value.

And I have no idea of what if going on. The same problem happens when trying to initialise the rest of the labels in the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
destination.newsTitle.text = "whatevertitle"
```

don't access outlets of the destination vc as they not yet loaded send a string and assign it to the label in the destination vc

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToNewsDetail" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? NewsDetailViewController {
                destination.newsLink = "whateverlink"
                destination.toSend = "whatevertitle"
        }
    }
}
class NewsDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var newsTitle:UILabel!
    var toSend = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.newsTitle.text = toSend
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `prepareForSegue` method, the `newsTitle` label is still not initialised, so it is `nil`.

Generally, you shouldn't set the target VC's view's properties in `prepareForSegue`. You should declare a `newsTitleText` property in `NewsDetailViewController`:

```
var newsTitleText: String!
```

And set this property instead:

```
destination.newsTitleText = "whatevertitle"
```

Then set the `newsTitle.text` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Hides the navigation bar.
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    newsTitle.text = newsTitleText
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the `prepare(for:sender:)` method is called, `NewsDetailViewController` has not loaded the view yet so you can't set the text on a label. What you want to do is create another property on `NewsDetailViewController` such as `var newsTitleText: String?`. Then in `viewDidLoad` you can call `newsTitle.text = newsTitleText`.